# background CSS property not applied after Ajax reload with Smoothstate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've a certain css line that I want to apply to my header after an Ajax load with SmoothState but for some reason it doesn't apply the background CSS property while it does others.

Here's a snippet of my code:

Ajax Function SmoothState:

```
  var settings = { 
   onAfter: function( $container ) {  
     vacaturepagina(); 
    }
   };
 $( '#page' ).smoothState( settings );
```

Custom script:

```
    function vacaturepagina(){ 
        $('.site-header .wrap').css({

                'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(103, 50, 81, 0), rgb(103, 50, 81))',
                'margin-top':'unset',
                'height': '180px'
        });
     }
     vacaturepagina();
```

The strange thing is that margin-top and height are applied but background isn't after an AJAX load. when I refresh the page it is applied correctly.

Anyone any thoughts?

Comment: maybe you need to add some cross-browser compatibility: look [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Sorry I had another script from another page which was executed too on this page

```
        onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex){

            $('.site-header .wrap').css({
                'background':''
            });
       }
```

This caused the background not to work on the other page when loaded with Ajax. It wasn't properly destroyed.